# TRANSFORM COLUMN IN ROW AND CONCATENATE

Tags: r

I have a `DF` and I want to do two transformations: (i) row to column and (ii) concatenate columns. This is my `DF`:

```
CAR <- c('BMW','BMW','BMW','FERRARI','FERRARI','VW')
DATE <- c('OCT','NOV','DEC','OCT','DEC','DEC')
TIME <- c(10,12,15,7,11,14)
QUANTITY <- c(115,101,95,88,130,101)
DF <- data.frame(CAR,DATA,TIME,QUANTITY)
```

I want to transform into this `DF2`:

```
CAR <- c('BMW','FERRARI','VW')
OCT <- c('10 N=(115)','7 N=(88)',' N=()')
NOV <- c('12 N=(101)',' N=()',' N=()')
DEC <- c('15 N=(95)','11 N=(130)','14 N=(101)')
DF2 <- data.frame(CAR,OCT,NOV,DEC)
```

See that the contents of the DATA column turned into 3 columns. Also, I concatenated `TIME` and `QUANTITY`, but included the letter “N” and the parentheses. Is this kind of transformation possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `sprintf/glue` to format the columns and then reshape with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>%
    mutate(TIMEQ = sprintf('%d N=(%d)', TIME, QUANTITY), .keep = 'unused') %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = DATE, values_from = TIMEQ)
```

By default, if the combination is missing, it returns `NA`, but if we want to fill with a custom value, use `values_fill`

```
DF %>%
    mutate(TIMEQ = sprintf('%d N=(%d)', TIME, QUANTITY), .keep = 'unused') %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = DATE, values_from = TIMEQ, values_fill = "N=())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  CAR     OCT        NOV        DEC       
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 BMW     10 N=(115) 12 N=(101) 15 N=(95) 
2 FERRARI 7 N=(88)   N=()       11 N=(130)
3 VW      N=()       N=()       14 N=(101)
```